# Only show selected rows when faceting with Altair?

Tags: python, altair

When I make this example using `altair`, the final plot shows all the data in both facets. However, I only want to show the data within each facet.

Does `altair` have an option for this? Or am I specifying the facet incorrectly?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
df = data.airports()
df = df[df['state'].isin(['MD', 'WY'])][0:12]

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('latitude'),
    alt.Y('name', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="latitude", op="mean", order='descending')),
    alt.Color('state'))

chart.facet(row='state')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altair's compound charts have shared scales by default. If you would like scales to be independent, this can be specified via the `resolve_scale()` method.

For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
df = data.airports()
df = df[df['state'].isin(['MD', 'WY'])][0:12]

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.X('latitude'),
    alt.Y('name', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="latitude", op="mean", order='descending')),
    alt.Color('state'))

chart.facet(row='state').resolve_scale(y='independent')
```

[image]